Why does the permutation of the indices ijk in the epsilon tensor imply the permutation of 123 when ijk are variables?
The epsilon tensor is defined as +1 when i,j,k are an even permutation of 1,2,3 and -1 when they are a uneven permutation of 1,2,3 and 0 when two Indices are the same. For example (I will just write the indices): ijk=123=1
ikj=132=-1
The point I dont get is that ikj could also be 123 because all the Indices are variables. But if they are variables why does the order in which they appear show the permutation of 123 and if ijk are fixed values why are they not written out as numbers?

The symbol you are referring to is known as the 3-dimensional Levi-Civita symbol. It is often use to calculate determinants of 3x3 matrices (and cross products of 3D vectors, which can be written as a determinant of a 3x3 matrix). In full notation, the determinant of the 3x3 matrix $\mathbf{A}$ whose $i$th row and $j$th column contain the value $a_{ij}$ is given by $$\det(\mathbf{A})=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3\epsilon_{ijk}a_{1i}a_{2j}a_{3k}$$ Often the sum from $1$ to $3$ is implied and the expression is written as $$\det(\mathbf{A})=\epsilon_{ijk}a_{1i}a_{2j}a_{3k}$$ But the point is that $i,j,k$ could each take any value from $1,2,3$, sometimes they all take different values, sometimes they take the same values. So the $i,j,k$ are not fixed but are variable, and the value of $\epsilon_{ijk}$ depends on these values for $i,j,k$
